# @output is not working in angular

Tags: angular5

I have created input box of string type button with a button referencing that value passing to parent component but having issues.

[Child Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yraTi.png)

[Parent Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QXaY.png)

[module.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlOn0.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post your code within code blocks directly into your post - it will help people figure out what's wrong quickly. In order to do so, just select the code in your editor, paste it in your question, then select it with mouse and hit Control+K or click the button in edit menu.

Comment: OK, thank you for the suggestion.